# Concatenating string overwriting previous string C#

Tags: c#, string, textbox, concatenation, overwrite

I have a program that gets numbers from the user and stores them in a list, then it takes each number and prints it on a textbox before printing the average. However, I have an logic error with adding two strings together. Here is the code that matters.

```
DataView.Text = "";
if (Comma)
{
    DataView.Text = Number.ToString();
}
else 
{
    DataView.Text += ", " + Number.ToString();
}
```

It checks if it needs to add a comma then adds according to that. I believe that this is the line that isn't working, but I could be wrong.

```
DataView.Text += ", " + Number.ToString();
```

I think that it removes the number that was there previously and just puts the number that is there now, which is not what I want, I want it to show both.

Comment: Can you show us the whole code ? Where does Comma come from as you are resetting the string in that if block.

Comment: Did you read this to your rubber duck?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging  If `Comma` or if `!Comma`...

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the code and stepped in to look at what's actually going on? (Your problem should get pretty obvious once you take a couple seconds to debug you app)

Comment: If this is indeed the actual code, you start with an empty string each time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your resetting the string to "" here

```
DataView.Text = "";
```

So ofcourse whenever you call

```
DataView.Text += ", " + Number.ToString();
```

It's only going to show

```
, 912837 (or whatever number)
```

Also, whenever you find that you already have a comma, you do

```
DataView.Text = Number.ToString();
```

Which should be

```
DataView.Text += Number.ToString();
```

If you want to append the number instead of replace.

Comment: He really has a weird problem in the context of the code he has written...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the complete context here but assuming you are iterating through the list, you will need to make sure you are not resetting the dataview's text value to empty inside the loop.